# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers

It challenges a **direct quote** from (in fact, the seeming **prime motivation** of) [the question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115356/what-is-the-reason-for-paying-more-capital-gains-tax-if-i-stay-in-the-same-house).

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't involved in deleting it and didn't see it before deletion. But my view is that even after editing, it doesn't answer the fundamentals of the question at all. The title and focus of the question is all about why capital gains tax is higher in one scenario than the other. The fact that the question included a slightly questionable assumption about the consequences of that disparity doesn't make a challenge to that assumption a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was deleted by 3 non-mod members. I'm not taking a position on this, just advising that it was not done by a moderator, and, given the recent Meta activity, or specifically, the lack thereof, I doubt you'll get an answer.

I offer this only for the fact that once a question is deleted, I don't know what visibility you have, and would prefer that you not assume it was a mod, who is then ignoring your query.

Comment: Thanks.  The only reason why I thought it *might* be a mod is because questions usually require a *lot* of delete votes.

Comment: No problem. I'm not a mind reader, but that was an easy one. Also why, sometimes I'll start a comment with I am not the DV, lest the OP think I am explaining my own DV.  Nothing is simple lately)

Comment: What does "DV" mean?

Comment: Down Vote, sorry

Comment: Yeah, II do that sometimes, too.